# How do browsers detect GIF image sizes?

Tags: html, image, http, browser, imagemagick

I was noticing that a GIF was being displayed with padding in FireFox 5 and IE 8. When I viewed the image size via FireBug, I noticed that it was a few pixels larger than expected.

> Expected height: 160px vs. actual height: 171px

When I opened the GIF in an image editor, the editor displayed the correct dimensions, however when I ran ImageMagick identify I received the following information:

```
newGif.gif GIF 200x160 200x171+0+5 PseudoClass 256c 30kb
```

If I modified the geometry to 200x160+0+0 the image displayed as I expected it to in FireFox. FireFox and IE 8 seemed to be referencing the Image's page geometry rather than dimensions! Is my analysis correct and if so is this true for all image types or just GIF's?

> Updated, I have included an image for your viewing pleasure! This image displays as 200 x 171 for me in FF, but is actually 200 x 160 when you download and view in a graphics program.

[image: here is the image]

Comment: It would be great if you could link an example. I'm curious to see this

Comment: Intersting, it looks like a difference between the GIF header and the ImageBlock.  It looks like this Image has an imageblock that is bigger than the size in the header.

http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gif.html

Comment: This thread is 10 years old but came in handy recently. Unfortunately the link above is dead. However, it is available at http://www33146ue.sakura.ne.jp/staff/iz/formats/gif.html. The Internet Wayback Machine found the active link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Header of this GIF file does not correspond to it's body.
[image]

Image dimensions are stored in 6th to 9th bytes and from the screen shot you can see that dimensions in the header are  00C8 x 00AB which is 200x171 but it's actual size is 200x160

So this image is not valid. There are no standardized behavior for parsing invalid gifs and that's why there is this inconsistency.

Most probably firefox preallocates place for images before they are fully downloaded, when an image is fully downloaded it is put into the center of preallocated space. and because preallocated space is 200x171 but the actual image is 200x160 you will see a border.

**EDIT:** After going through GIF format reference it appears that GIF does allow this. So the image is valid. So here's what's actually going on here:
GIF format consists from several blocks. There is a header block and one or more(*if the image is animated*) image blocks (*there could be other blocks as well, but they are not connected with the issue*). Header block holds some information about the image, including it's width and height. However each image block has it's own width and height as well. So what happens with the image in question that it has the main image size as 200x171 but the single frame with the size 200x160. So most editing programs and libraries which doesn't support animated gifs will extract the first frame and display it with the size 200x160 the browsers and editors which do support animation should display it with the full size of 200x171.

**PS** Every image block has image top and image left position. It seems that by allowing frames to be smaller than canvas, and allowing to move frame's position on the canvas, GIF's developers tried to shave couple of bytes of the animated gif files. I wonder if any of the modern graphic editors take advantage of that... probably not... :)

1. [GIF format byte order](http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gif.html)

Comment: No, the image dimensions of the .GIF are correct if you use ImageMagick identify or a similar tool. It is the image canvas size that is being returned in the header. I have found some literature that .GIF images respect the image canvas, whereas other image types do not. I do not follow that the image is invalid.

Comment: Indeed after a bit deeper research it seems that the image is indeed is valid. I'll edit the answer in a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I could find literature that mentioned .GIF images reference a virtual canvas, but none of the explanations explained the mechanics. It didn't make sense until now!

Comment: Yeah, it was quite interesting to research. I love those old file types. They would go to almost any lengths to save couple of bytes here and there :D

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the GIF is an animated format, so it could contain several images located on different positions of the geometry frame. Therefore, the browser should reserve place for a whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the picture, and right click->properties, it'll state that it is 200x160, also of note when you preview the picture in windows black bars are added to the image, which is strange. If you open it in ms paint (just for demonstration purposes) you'll notice that the image is padded with black bars, and when you look at the file->properties it says the image is now 200x171.

The most likely scenario is that the file header says it's 200x160 (which windows/browsers etc looks at to tell you the image size quickly), while the actual image block is 200x171. The black bars don't show up in browsers as they are likely transparent, but as ms paint and windows preview don't support transparency, the black bars show in them. Further the correct size is found in mspaint because the header data is thrown out, and the properties show you properties of their data structure now holding the image block to image editing, similarly if you load the image into mspaint, modify the image to remove the black bars, save, and then put that picture into your browser then the padding will disappear.

Most of the time, when loading the image of an image file, only horizontal resolution of the image is required, and the image block is just read for the horizontal resolution for every vertical row of the image, when you read the end of the image block, you're at the end of the image, so heeding the vertical resolution isn't mandatory to load the image from it. This is why the image appears normal, and doesn't crop off the bottom edge.

As for why this image isn't padded in other browsers. I can only assume that this padding images with boarders is a standard of sorts that they have come to expect in image files, and when confronted with an image block larger than the file header specifies, they crop it toward the centre of the image block to the best of their ability